# can't find detailed, specific documentation for using markdown on github project and user pages

Tags: github, markdown, github-pages

I'm in the process of adding github pages to some of my repos and to my user page.  For many of the web pages, I want to use Markdown formatting.

However, as I can only find [vague, undetailed](http://help.github.com/pages/) information about how to do this, I'm doing trial-and-error to figure out how it works.

Where is the real documentation?  The gory details?

---

[Here](http://xlson.com/2010/11/09/getting-started-with-github-pages.html) is the best information I've found so far, which says:

- use the special branch name `gh-pages` to create a site for a project repo
- a three-line incantation at the top of the file is necessary:

  ```
  ---
  title: something
  ---
  ```
- the suffix gets changed to `.html`

But I'm left with many questions about details, such as:

- can I import css files?
- what does that "title" blurb actually do?
- what suffix do the files need to have?

etc.   So I'd really like to see the detailed documentation for all of the features.

---

Please note that this question is not about how to use Markdown syntax, but how to harness github's magic for automatically creating html from Markdown within the scope of user and project pages.

Answer (score 0):

Only files with extensions `.md` or `.markdown` will be translated to HTML on a GitHub User Page.

Files with extensions `.html` and `.textile` are *not* translated, according to my tries.

Note that UTF8 encoding should be avoided.

Comment: @MattFenwick: It mentions that near the top of the YAML Front Matter page: https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/YAML-Front-Matter.